# Need telegram bot to edit a function from another file

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

As the title says. I need my telegram bot to take user input, and use that to change some values on another function from another file. I already got the file to be successfully run from the bot, but I can't figure out how to change values first. I am using Python-Telegram-bot.

here is the code I need to edit that is in a separate file (call.py)

```
call = client.calls.create(
     machine_detection='Enable',
     url='https://ngrok.io/main',
     to='',
     from_=''
)
```

I need to edit the "to" and "from" field(s) in this code above.
The code I use to run this from my bot is as follows:

```
def update(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Enter number :\n'
                              'e.g. 18004585478\n')
    update.message.reply_text('Calling...')
    exec(open("call.py").read())
```

I am pretty new to all this so I know the code is not good at all. I have read that I should be using ConversationHandler or CommandHandler but I honestly am not sure how to implement it.

I edited the code based on what Alexey suggested and now am stuck on a similar issue.

```
def update(update, context):
   update.message.reply_text('Enter number:\n'
                             'e.g. 18004585478\n'
                             'Number Must begin with 1')
   from_number = update.message.text
   update.message.reply_text('Enter number:\n'
                             'e.g. 18004585478\n'
                             'Number Must begin with 1')
   to_number = update.message.text
   update.message.reply_text('Calling...')
   call_state = call.make_call(to_number, from_number)
```

The Telegram bot just runs all the code at once, it doesn't stop and wait for any input from the number fields. How do I go about implementing MessageHandler to make the bot stop and accept input to pass along to call_state, then execute call_state at the end?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change the code, you need to use arguments to pass the data you wanted to.

In `call.py` you can make a funciton

```
def make_call(to_number, from_number):
    call = client.calls.create(
        machine_detection='Enable',
        url='https://ngrok.io/main',
        to=to_number,
        from=from_number,
    )
    return call
```

In your `update` function just use the function by giving it the necessary values

```
import call
def update(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Enter number :\n'
                              'e.g. 18004585478\n')
    update.message.reply_text('Calling...')
    call_state = call.make_call(to_number='0123456789', from_number='9876543210')
    # use call_state ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now how do I go about executing call_state?

Comment: @Ace Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Telegram bots

Comment: Thank you, you did help a lot. I ran into a seperate problem though where telegram does not wait for my input to edit the to and from_number fields. It just runs everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

What Alexey stated ended up working with very slight modifications.

I took what Alexey posted and deleted the numbers and turned them into a variable I could edit from my other script.

```
def make_call(to_number, from_number):
    call = client.calls.create(
        machine_detection='Enable',
        url='https:snip/main',
        to=to_number,
        from_=from_number
    )
    print(call.sid)
```

Then in the other file I defined the variables and executed them by importing the file I needed to edit by using `user_data[FROM] = update.message.text` `and user_data[TO] = update.message.text`.

then calling the funciton.

`call_state = call.make_call({user_data[TO]}, {user_data[FROM]})`

Dont forget to add `user_data = {}` at the top of your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).